# create data frame in spark from unparsed text string

Tags: scala, parsing, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I am using Scala and Spark to analyze some data.
Sorry I am absolute novice in this area.

I have data in the following format (below)
I want to create RDD to filter data, group and transform data.

Currently I have rdd with list of unparsed strings
I have created it from rawData: list of strings

```
val rawData  ( this is ListBuffer[String] )
val rdd = sc.parallelize(rawData)
```

How can I create data set to manipulate data? 
I want to have objects in Rdd with named fields line ob.name,  obj.year and so on
What is the right approach?

Should I create data frame for this?

Raw data strings looks like this :  this is list of strings, with space separated values

Column meaning: "name",  year" , "month", "tmax", "tmin", "afdays", "rainmm", "sunhours"

```
aberporth    1941  10    ---     ---    ---    106.2     ---
aberporth    1941  11    ---     ---    ---     92.3     ---
aberporth    1941  12    ---     ---    ---     86.5     ---
aberporth    1942   1    5.8     2.1    ---    114.0    58.0
aberporth    1942   2    4.2    -0.6    ---     13.8    80.3
aberporth    1942   3    9.7     3.7    ---     58.0   117.9
aberporth    1942   4   13.1     5.3    ---     42.5   200.1
aberporth    1942   5   14.0     6.9    ---    101.1   215.1
aberporth    1942   6   16.2     9.9    ---      2.3   269.3
aberporth    1942   7   17.4    11.3    12     70.2*   185.0
aberporth    1942   8   18.7    12.3    5-     78.5   141.9
aberporth    1942   9   16.4    10.7    123    146.8   129.1#
aberporth    1942  10   13.1     8.2    125    131.1    82.1l
```

--- - means no data, i think I can put 0 to this colument.

70.2* , 129.1# , 82.l  -  * , # and l here should be filtred

Please point me to right direction.

I have found one of the possible solution here:
https://medium.com/@mrpowers/manually-creating-spark-dataframes-b14dae906393

This example looks good:

```
val someData = Seq(
  Row(8, "bat"),
  Row(64, "mouse"),
  Row(-27, "horse")
)

val someSchema = List(
  StructField("number", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("word", StringType, true)
)

val someDF = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
  StructType(someSchema)
)
```

How can I transform list of strings to Seq of Row  ?

Comment: The question is how to create data set from raw unparsed data in Spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the data as a text file and replace `---` with `0` and remove special characters or filter out. ( I have replaced in below example)

Create a case class to represent the data

```
case class Data(
                 name: String, year: String, month: Int, tmax: Double,
                 tmin: Double, afdays: Int, rainmm: Double, sunhours: Double
             )
```

Read a file

```
val data = spark.read.textFile("file path")  //read as a text file
  .map(_.replace("---", "0").replaceAll("-|#|\\*", ""))  //replace special charactes 
  .map(_.split("\\s+"))
  .map(x =>  // create Data object for each record
    Data(x(0), x(1), x(2).toInt, x(3).toDouble, x(4).toDouble, x(5).toInt, x(6).toDouble, x(7).replace("l", "").toDouble)
  )
```

Now you get a `Dataset[Data]` which is a dataset parsed from the text.

Output:

```
+---------+----+-----+----+----+------+------+--------+
|name     |year|month|tmax|tmin|afdays|rainmm|sunhours|
+---------+----+-----+----+----+------+------+--------+
|aberporth|1941|10   |0.0 |0.0 |0     |106.2 |0.0     |
|aberporth|1941|11   |0.0 |0.0 |0     |92.3  |0.0     |
|aberporth|1941|12   |0.0 |0.0 |0     |86.5  |0.0     |
|aberporth|1942|1    |5.8 |2.1 |0     |114.0 |58.0    |
|aberporth|1942|2    |4.2 |0.6 |0     |13.8  |80.3    |
|aberporth|1942|3    |9.7 |3.7 |0     |58.0  |117.9   |
|aberporth|1942|4    |13.1|5.3 |0     |42.5  |200.1   |
|aberporth|1942|5    |14.0|6.9 |0     |101.1 |215.1   |
|aberporth|1942|6    |16.2|9.9 |0     |2.3   |269.3   |
|aberporth|1942|7    |17.4|11.3|12    |70.2  |185.0   |
|aberporth|1942|8    |18.7|12.3|5     |78.5  |141.9   |
|aberporth|1942|9    |16.4|10.7|123   |146.8 |129.1   |
|aberporth|1942|10   |13.1|8.2 |125   |131.1 |82.1    |
+---------+----+-----+----+----+------+------+--------+
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Shankar! This is what I mean.  I see to dots before replaceAll.  Is it typo?  I la ready has spark context so I have slightly modified the code   val data = sc.textFile(allDataTextFile)    .    What I don't understand how can I get access to values? val first = data.take(1) ;  println("name: " + first.name)      It gives me error: DataExample.scala:201:26: value name is not a member of Array[Data]
[error] println("name: " + first.name)

Comment: If you use sparkContext you get RDD[Data] so you need .toDS method at last to convert as a dataset.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I need import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset to use toDS method.   then I can write something like val dataset = data.toDS ;  dataset.show                   How can I include sql to sbt curently I have only spark entry:  libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.4.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.2"     is 1.6.2 corrent version? How can I check it?